# Ordering y-axis of seaborn boxplot?

Tags: python, seaborn

I have the following view: [image]

but I'd like to have the y-axis here ordered so the `num_engagements` field is increasing as the y-axis goes up instead of the reverse case here. I've tried playing with the order field in the seaborn options, but if I set `order=['num_engagements']` then I just get a blank plot as a result.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in a list of all the y-axis labels to your order keyword. The following would achieve what you want:

```
sns.boxplot(y='num_engagements', x='channel_spend1', showfliers=False, 
            orient='h', data=rep_data_imputed, order=['13','12','11','10','9'])
```

One thing to note, currently your number of engagement is being treated as a categorical variable, thus I specified the order as `['13','12','11','10','9']`, with single quotation marks. If it doesn't work, try `[13,12,11,10,9]`