# X-axis out of order seaborn histplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to create a [`seaborn histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) and am almost done, however, I noticed that my x-axis is out of order.

```
original_data = {0.0: 29076, 227.92: 26401, 473.51: 12045, 195.98: 7500, 495.0: 3750, 53.83: 3750, 385.0: 3750, 97.08: 3750, 119.39: 3750, 118.61: 3750, 30.0: 3750, 13000.0: 3750, 553.22: 3750, 1420.31: 3750, 1683.03: 3750, 1360.48: 3750, 1361.16: 3750, 1486.66: 3750, 1398.5: 3750, 4324.44: 3750, 4500.0: 3750, 1215.51: 3750, 1461.27: 3750, 772.5: 3750, 3330.0: 3750, 915.75: 3750, 2403.1225: 3750, 1119.5: 3750, 2658.13: 3618, 492.0: 1818, 10000.0: 1809, 0.515: 1809, 118.305: 1809, 215.0: 1809, 513.0: 1809, 237.5: 1809, 15452.5: 1809, 377838.0: 1809, 584983.0: 1809, 10772.61: 1809, 883.87: 1809, 110494.0: 1809, 2727.0: 1809, 1767.0: 1809, 4792.5: 1809, 6646.5: 1809, 7323.75: 1809, 4399.5: 1809, 2737.5: 1809, 9088.5: 1809, 6405.0: 1809, 0.36: 1809, 112.055: 1809, 247.5: 1809, 232.5: 1809, 18000.0: 1809, 38315.0: 1809, 8100.0: 1809, 63115.34: 1809, 27551.0: 1809, 6398.58: 1809, 78.0: 1809, 26.0: 1809, 1413.0: 1809, 2230.5: 1809, 604.5: 1809, 4037.25: 1809, 18507.0: 1809, 732.75: 1809, 22665.0: 1809, 12212.25: 1809, 17833.5: 1809, 4177.5: 1809, 1521.0: 1809, 2307.0: 1809, 1873.5: 1809, 1948.5: 1809, 1182.0: 1809, 1473.0: 1695}

import pandas as pd, numpy as np, seaborn as sns, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
costs = df['evals'].to_numpy()
original_data = Counter(df['evals'].to_numpy())
new = []
for c in costs:
    if c >= 0 and c < 100:
        new.append('<\$100')
    elif c >= 100 and c < 500:
        new.append('<\$500 and >= \$100')
    elif c >= 500 and c < 2000:
        new.append('<\$500 and >= \$2000')
    elif c >= 2000 and c < 5000:
        new.append('<\$2000 and >= \$500')
    elif c >= 5000 and c < 10000:
        new.append('<\$10000 and >= \$5000')
    elif c >= 10000 and c < 20000:
        new.append('<\$20000 and >= \$10000')
    elif c >= 20000 and c < 40000:
        new.append('<\$40000 and >= \$20000')        
    else:
        new.append('>= \$40000')
order = ['<\$100', '<\$500 and >= \$100', '<\$500 and >= \$2000', '<\$2000 and >= \$500',
         '<\$10000 and >= \$5000', '<\$20000 and >= \$10000', '<\$40000 and >= \$20000']
plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
sns.histplot(data=new, stat='probability', kde=True)
plt.show()
```

Displays:
[image]

Adding `order` argument [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57881260/ordering-y-axis-of-seaborn-boxplot) creates the following error(s):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\wundermahn\eval_plots.py", line 28, in <module>
    sns.histplot(data=new, stat='probability', kde=True, order=order)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\seaborn\distributions.py", line 1435, in histplot
    **kwargs,
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\seaborn\distributions.py", line 508, in plot_univariate_histogram
    scout = self.ax.fill_between([], [], color=color, **plot_kws)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1565, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5229, in fill_between
    collection = mcoll.PolyCollection(polys, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 1072, in __init__
    Collection.__init__(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.update(kwargs)
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 1006, in update
    ret = [_update_property(self, k, v) for k, v in props.items()]
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 1006, in <listcomp>
    ret = [_update_property(self, k, v) for k, v in props.items()]
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 1002, in _update_property
    .format(type(self).__name__, k))
AttributeError: 'PolyCollection' object has no property 'order'
```

How can I force that order on my `x-axis`?

Comment: Well, `sns.histplot` doesn't have an `order` parameter (contrary to the linked `sns.boxlpot`). Maybe you'd like to consider `sns.barplot` (which does have an `order` parameter)? Or a `sns.countplot`?

Comment: @JohanC the main goal is to calculate the probability of the "price" falling within a certain bin. How can that be emulated using a `barplot`?

Comment: @JohanC that is because I was unable to properly set the `bins` parameter in `seaborn` to create those same bins and instead mapped them to text. If there is a solution inherently using the `histplot` parameters, I'd be interested.

Comment: @JohanC I was unable to create bins of that size, no matter what I entered for the bin parameter, the `x-axis` would move to the maximum value in the array (a single is `600,000` while most others are `< 40000`)

Comment: @JohanC to provide the original data that is being mapped into text for anyone who is interested in helping me answer this question. That dictionary of data is a `Counter(df['evals'].to_numpy())`

Comment: I don't think it makes any sense to show the KDE curve here.

Comment: @mwaskom you're not wrong, but, business requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a bar plot, using `np.histogram` to count how many values are in each bin. The bins need to be set explicitly, as they aren't equally spaced.

Using `sns.histplot` directly on the `costs` array would show bars with all different widths, which looks quite confusing. Also note that you can't show a kde when the x-axis isn't numeric.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter, ScalarFormatter

original_data = {0.0: 29076, 227.92: 26401, 473.51: 12045, 195.98: 7500, 495.0: 3750, 53.83: 3750, 385.0: 3750, 97.08: 3750, 119.39: 3750, 118.61: 3750, 30.0: 3750, 13000.0: 3750, 553.22: 3750, 1420.31: 3750, 1683.03: 3750, 1360.48: 3750, 1361.16: 3750, 1486.66: 3750, 1398.5: 3750, 4324.44: 3750, 4500.0: 3750, 1215.51: 3750, 1461.27: 3750, 772.5: 3750, 3330.0: 3750, 915.75: 3750, 2403.1225: 3750, 1119.5: 3750, 2658.13: 3618, 492.0: 1818, 10000.0: 1809, 0.515: 1809, 118.305: 1809, 215.0: 1809, 513.0: 1809, 237.5: 1809, 15452.5: 1809, 377838.0: 1809, 584983.0: 1809, 10772.61: 1809, 883.87: 1809, 110494.0: 1809, 2727.0: 1809, 1767.0: 1809, 4792.5: 1809, 6646.5: 1809, 7323.75: 1809, 4399.5: 1809, 2737.5: 1809, 9088.5: 1809, 6405.0: 1809, 0.36: 1809, 112.055: 1809, 247.5: 1809, 232.5: 1809, 18000.0: 1809, 38315.0: 1809, 8100.0: 1809, 63115.34: 1809, 27551.0: 1809, 6398.58: 1809, 78.0: 1809, 26.0: 1809, 1413.0: 1809, 2230.5: 1809, 604.5: 1809, 4037.25: 1809, 18507.0: 1809, 732.75: 1809, 22665.0: 1809, 12212.25: 1809, 17833.5: 1809, 4177.5: 1809, 1521.0: 1809, 2307.0: 1809, 1873.5: 1809, 1948.5: 1809, 1182.0: 1809, 1473.0: 1695}

costs = list(original_data.values())
bins = [0, 100, 500, 2000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 40000, 1000000]

bin_values, bin_edges = np.histogram(costs, bins=bins)
labels = [f'< \${b0} and\n>= \${b1}' for b0, b1 in zip(bins[1:-2], bins[2:-1])]
labels = [f'< \${bins[1]}'] + labels + [f'>= \${bins[-2]}']
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
sns.barplot(x=labels, y=bin_values / bin_values.sum(), color='dodgerblue', ax=ax)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Alternatively, `sns.histplot()` could be displayed with a logarithmic x-axis to make the bar widths more equal while maintaining a numeric axis. In that case a kde could be calculated on the logs of the values.

```py
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

bins = [0, 100, 500, 2000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 40000, 100000]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
sns.histplot(costs, bins=bins, stat='probability', ec='black', lw=1, ax=ax)

xs = np.logspace(2, np.log10(bins[-1] ), 500)
kde = gaussian_kde(np.log(costs) )
ax.plot(xs, kde(np.log(xs)), color='crimson')

ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xticks(bins[1:-1])
ax.set_xticks([], minor=True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
```

[image: plot with logarithmic x-axis]

Comment: The usage of the `log` was brilliant. I did need to change your `log` to `log1p`, but otherwise, this worked great.

Comment: If you pass `log_scale` to `histplot` it will do both the binning and the kde evaluation in log space, fyi, there's no need to compute the kde manually.

Comment: That's interesting. I've been experimenting a bit. `histplot` seems to need bins=np.log10([1, 100, 500, ...])` when `log_scale=True`, but for some reason cuts off the left of the kde too soon (for the given data).  What does work, is first call `histplot` and then `kdeplot(..., log_scale=True)` on a `twinx` ax (and decrease the xlims).