# Set order on sns histplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to set the order of a stacked `histplot` using seaborn. Below, then plot is fine but I'm hoping to alter the order so it reads `Up, Down, Left, Right` when reading left to right.

I get an error when trying to pass `order` or `col_order`.

```
raise AttributeError('{!r} object has no property {!r}'

AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no property 'order'
```

It works fine when not passing the order though.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({      
    'Label' : ['A','B','C','B','B','C','C','B','B','A','C','A','B','A','C','A'],   
    'Item' : ['Up','Left','Up','Left','Down','Right','Up','Down','Right','Down','Right','Up','Up','Right','Down','Left'],        
   })

g = sns.histplot(data = df, 
            x = 'Item', 
            hue = 'Label',
            #order = ['Up','Down','Left','Right'],
            multiple = 'fill', 
            shrink = 0.8, 
            discrete = True,
            legend = True,
            )
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65686685/x-axis-out-of-order-seaborn-histplot

Comment: You can use `ax = sns.histplot(...., hue_order = ['Up','Down','Left','Right'])` (making the column categorical is another nice solution).  Also note that `histplot` is an axes-level function, that returns an `ax`. You might want to check out [figure-level vs axes-level functions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions). Using `g = ` for axes-level functions makes it more confusing to find out how to refine a seaborn plot via matplotlib.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot order it from within `seaborn`. You could order it from `pandas` though. To provide a custom sorting order for strings, you can turn the `Item` column into a [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html), and specify the order in the second parameter.

After that, you will get the plot ordered as you want:

```py
df['Item'] = pd.Categorical(df['Item'], ['Up','Down','Left','Right'])
```

The full code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({      
    'Label' : ['A','B','C','B','B','C','C','B','B','A','C','A','B','A','C','A'],   
    'Item' : ['Up','Left','Up','Left','Down','Right','Up','Down','Right','Down','Right','Up','Up','Right','Down','Left'],        
   })


df['Item'] = pd.Categorical(df['Item'], ['Up','Down','Left','Right'])

g = sns.histplot(data = df, 
            x = 'Item', 
            hue = 'Label',
            #order = ['Up','Down','Left','Right'],
            multiple = 'fill', 
            shrink = 0.8, 
            discrete = True,
            legend = True,
            )
```